# GetDirectoryEntry not returning all properties

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to query AD to retrieve user data.

Query works fine, but when enumerating through the properties returned via GetDirectoryEntry
I am not able to see all the attributes I am seeing in Active Directory Explorer.

Code snippet below:

```
offEntry = pResult.GetDirectoryEntry();
foreach (PropertyValueCollection o in offEntry.Properties)
{
    Debug.Print(o.PropertyName + " = " + o.Value.ToString());
}
```

I am seeing attributes like "displayName" and "SAMAccountName" etc, but not the attributes I really want, ex: "postalCode", "streetAddress".

I have tried searching for a solution for this specific problem but have come to a dead end.
What am I missing???

Regards
Peter

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a searcher class like this.

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                search.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + userAccount + ")";
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
```

then load the properties you want via the line

```
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
```

then in your `SearchResult` you will be able to read the properties

Comment: @peter give this a go, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907 if you have access to the AD Domain you should be able to use this to see all the properties within your AD. I have had a look in the AD that I have access to and I cannot see those two properties so unless they are in the your AD you will not be able to output them.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old, but maybe it helps someone else:

1. Leaving PropertiesToLoad of DirectorySearcher **Empty** (no .add) will result in all properties **that already contain a value**.
2. the SearchResult has a method for returning the actual DirectoryEntry: result.GetDirectoryEntry(). Which (I am still trying to prevent that) will load all Properties that have been filled with values.
3. The DirectoryEntry has a "InvokeSet" Method to fill Properties that are not filled yet, after that they will be returned. (There is also a "InvokeGet" Method, havent tried that one out, but maybe it helps getting empty Properties)